# How to pass an object of type XmlDocument as a URI

Tags: c#

I created an `XML` object from `JSON`,

But I need to create another object that only accepts a `URI` of `XML` file in its constructor,

But the `XML` is not saved as a file on my computer,

So how can I build that object that only accepts a `URI`?

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonText);
MapShapeReader.Source = new Uri(?);
```

Comment: What is exactly your question - how do convert json to xml and what does the code even do ?

Comment: No, I already created an XML object from JSON,
But I need to create another object that only accepts a URI in its constructor, but the XML is not saved as a file on my computer, so how can I build that object that only accepts a URI?

Comment: That's something you could've mentioned in your original question - since I did not get that part of your description.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here (I'm responding to your comment, not really the original question). But an URI is a pointer to a resource - so you can't "pass the object" as an URI, you can only point to it.

So either create a point where you (re-) create the XML object when requested and return that object as a stream (1).

Or store the object as a file locally (and in a public reachable location) and return the URL including the newly created file as URI (2).